# Android button border dynamically

Tags: android, button, border

I am having a button, without any text only with background color. In `onClick()` event of the button I need to set the button border without the `xml` specification. I tried gradient rectangle shape as background `drawable` to the button which is not flexible for my layout.

How can I set border with specific color to the button?

Here is my code.

```
    Button btnBlackColor=new Button(this);
    int mButtonWidth=100;
    btnBlackColor.setWidth(mButtonWidth);
    btnBlackColor.setHeight(mButtonWidth);
    btnBlackColor.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);  

    btnBlackColor.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(View v)
      {
        GradientDrawable btnShape = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.BOTTOM_TOP, new int[]{Color.BLUE,Color.LTGRAY});
        btnShape.setCornerRadius(0);
        btnShape.setSize(mButtonWidth, mButtonWidth);
        btnShape.setBounds(10, 10, mButtonWidth, mButtonWidth);
        ClipDrawable btnClip = new ClipDrawable(btnShape, Gravity.LEFT,ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL);

        btnShape = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.BOTTOM_TOP, new int[]{Color.BLACK, Color.DKGRAY});
        btnShape.setCornerRadius(0); 
        btnShape.setSize(mButtonWidth, mButtonWidth);
        btnShape.setBounds(5, 5, mButtonWidth, mButtonWidth);


        LayerDrawable btnLayer= new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[]{btnShape, btnClip});

        btnBlackColor.setBackgroundDrawable(btnLayer); 
      }
    });
```

Comment: "I am having a button, without any text only with background color" -- this will neither look nor behave like a button, as what makes a button appear to respond to taps is its background as a `StateListDrawable`.

Comment: How can I add StateListDrawable without the xml specification.?

Comment: `StateListDrawable` is a Java class. You are welcome to create instances of it and configure those instances as you see fit. That being said, since ~99.44% of users of `StateListDrawable` do so via XML, you will probably find relatively few examples of managing one via Java.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found solution.

```
    GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable();
    drawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
    drawable.setStroke(5, Color.MAGENTA);
    drawable.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    btnBlackColor.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

Use these values and set to button background drawable. Now, the button looks with border in MAGENTA color.

Comment: great it also helpful for me. +1

Comment: how can i set image and then add stroke to it?

Answer (score 0):

Use selector in your xml background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"><!-- pressed -->
       <shape>...</shape>
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_hovered="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- hovered -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Every state of the burton may be a shape, look the properties you can modify:

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape=["rectangle" | "oval" | "line" | "ring"] >
    <corners
        android:radius="integer"
        android:topLeftRadius="integer"
        android:topRightRadius="integer"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="integer"
        android:bottomRightRadius="integer" />
    <gradient
        android:angle="integer"
        android:centerX="integer"
        android:centerY="integer"
        android:centerColor="integer"
        android:endColor="color"
        android:gradientRadius="integer"
        android:startColor="color"
        android:type=["linear" | "radial" | "sweep"]
        android:useLevel=["true" | "false"] />
    <padding
        android:left="integer"
        android:top="integer"
        android:right="integer"
        android:bottom="integer" />
    <size
        android:width="integer"
        android:height="integer" />
    <solid
        android:color="color" />
    <stroke
        android:width="integer"
        android:color="color"
        android:dashWidth="integer"
        android:dashGap="integer" />
</shape>
```

By code you can use a `StateListDrawable` to make the selector, for the shape use a `DrawableShape` please look arpt these links:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ShapeDrawable.html

Comment: I need to set this without xml file. How can I set these values.?

Comment: What exactly do you need to do? setBackgroundDrawable is not usefull for you?

Comment: While clicking the button, how can I highlight the button.? I prefer it may be a border.

Comment: Please look at the answer with the new edition. The border can be modified by stroke property. BR

Comment: Yes, But I am struggling to add those specified parameters by code. Could you please help me.?

Comment: Look at the end of the EDITED answer, althougt and is just a question, why do you need do this by code?