# Setting border around Button dynamically?

Tags: android, button, border

Is it possible to set a border around a button dynamically in Android? I can use it statically with stroke in a shape but I do not know how to do it from code.

Comment: A possible copy of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15187609/android-button-border-dynamically

Answer (score 0):

It's deprecated in newer versions of Android, but I use the `setBackgroundDrawable()` call to change how our buttons look dynamically in code:

```
            myButton.setBackgroundDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_gray));
```

If you define a drawable that has the border style you want that should properly update it when you need to.

If you're only using a later version of the API, you should be able to just call `myButton.setBackground()` instead.